# Comparing norms on tensor products of matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-analysis, tensor-products

Given a Hilbert space $H$, let $S_1(H)$ denote the space of trace-class operators on $H$, with the trace-class norm or Schatten 1-norm. That is
$$ \Vert T \Vert_1 = \sum_{j\geq 1} |s_j| $$
where $(s_1,s_2,\dots)$ is the sequence of eigenvalues of the operator $|T|=(T^*T)^{1/2})$ written in any order.

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert spaces of dimention $n$ and $m$ respectively. Let $H_1\otimes_2 H_2$ denote their Hilbert-space tensor product (hence, an inner product space of dimension $nm$).
Consider the map $$\varphi:S_1(H_1)\hat{\otimes}S_1(H_2)\to S_1(H_1\otimes_2 H_2),$$ which is defined by 
$$\varphi( A \otimes B) (\xi_1\otimes\xi_2) = (A\xi_1 )\otimes (B\xi_2) \quad(\xi_1\in H_1, \xi_2\in H_2) $$

Is it the case that $$\Vert\varphi^{-1}\Vert=\min\lbrace{m‎, ‎n}\rbrace ?$$
Here, $\hat{\otimes}$ denotes the projective tensor product of Banach spaces.

Comment: And the question would be "How can you prove that the norm of $\phi^{-1}$ is the minimum of $m$ and $n$?"? This is not very clear from the way you phrased it.

Comment: Please choose a title which describes your question in particular.

Comment: When you say "projective tensor product norm " - is this the Banach space version or the operator space version?

Comment: And what is the norm on $H_1\hat{\otimes} H_2$? Hilbertian? or the projective tensor product of Banach spaces? I think the question in its current form needs to be clarified

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. Indeed,I am trying to find the proof of PROPOSITION 2.4 of johnson's paper(NON-AMENABILITY OF THE FOURIER ALGEBRA OF A COMPACT GROUP). (http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1112%2Fjlms%2F50.2.361)                                  @MikaeldelaSalle

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Johnson's paper is odd in the sense that he reproves certain things about A(G) which are special cases of known results, so occasionally the arguments in that paper can be shortened if one uses more advanced tools.

Comment: The original version of your question had some notational errors and some non-standard use of terminology. I have rewritten it to obtain what I think is the question you wanted to ask. By the way, the two volumes of _Abstract Harmonic Analysis_ are by Hewitt **and Ross**

Comment: yea, you are quite right. this is the question that i wanted to ask.

Comment: @R.N  I am sorry that my question is not  related to your main question but is related to the trace norm you mentioned in your question. What is the precise location of  extreme points of the unit ball of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with trace norm $\parallel T \parallel_1=\sum s_i$?The extreme points of operator norm is $O(n)$ but what about trace norm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Revised answer:

(Notation from p 61ff of the reference below).
Note that for trace class norm we have 
$\mathcal{B}(H_1) = H_1 \hat\otimes H_1' = H_1\hat \otimes H_1$. For operator norm we have $\mathcal{B}(H_1) = H_1\hat{\hat\otimes} H_1'= H_1\hat{\hat\otimes} H_1$ where the tensor product is now the inductive one (also called $\epsilon$-tensor product). Using this and finite dimensionality we then can write
$\varphi:\mathcal{B}(H_1)\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{B}(H_2)\to\mathcal{B}(H_1\hat{\otimes}H_2)$
as the natural isomorphism
$$
(H_1 \hat\otimes H_1)\, \hat\otimes\, (H_2 \hat\otimes H_2) \to
(H_1 \hat\otimes H_2)\hat\otimes (H_1 \hat\otimes H_2)' =
(H_1 \hat\otimes H_2)\hat\otimes (H_1 \hat{\hat\otimes} H_2)
$$
which is $Id\,\hat\otimes\,j$ where $j:H_1 \hat\otimes H_2\to H_1 \hat{\hat\otimes} H_2$
is the embedding (here iso) of trace class norm into operator norm. The norm of $j$ is indeed $min\{\dim(H_1,\dim H_2)$, and the norm of $j^{-1}$ is its inverse, which can be seen by fixing bases and then writing any operator $A:H_1\to H_2$ as $U_2\circ D\circ U_1$ for isometries $U_i$ and a diagonal operator $D$.

## Ah,

I see now that the question changed. Here is the version for the new question:
$$
(H_1 \hat\otimes H_1)\, \hat\otimes\, (H_2 \hat\otimes H_2) =
(H_1 \hat\otimes H_2)\, \hat\otimes\, (H_1 \hat\otimes H_2) 
\to
(H_1 \otimes_2 H_2)\hat\otimes (H_1 \otimes_2 H_2)' =
(H_1 \otimes_2 H_2)\hat\otimes (H_1 \otimes_2 H_2)
$$
which is $i\hat\otimes i$ where $i: H_1 \hat\otimes H_2 \to H_1 \otimes_2 H_2$ is the natural iso. Its norm is the norm of the embedding $\ell^1\to \ell^2$ for the s-numbers.

- Johann Cigler, Viktor Losert, Peter W. Michor: Banach modules and functors on categories of Banach spaces. Lecture Notes in Pure and Applied Mathematics 46, Marcel Dekker Inc., New York, Basel, (1979) [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/banach_modules_and_functors.pdf)

Comment: I think your argument with reasonable tensor norms merely shows that $\varphi$ has norm $\leq 1$, not that $\varphi^{-1}$ has norm $\leq 1$.

Comment: You are right; my mistake.

Comment: Just for sake of interest: it turns out that if one defines the projective tensor product in the category of _operator spaces and completely bounded maps_, then we have $T(H_1)\hat{\otimes}_{\rm op} T(H_2) = T(H_1\otimes_2 H_2)$, where $T$ denotes trace-class (i.e. Schatten-1)